# Make "Arrow Up" button in interactive python mode continue from where it left off

Tags: python, linux, windows, read-eval-print-loop, python-interactive

## Problem

When I was using Windows, the "Arrow Up" button would continue where it left off in the Python REPL in the terminal, meaning: say I wrote lines `l_1`, `l_2`, `l_3`, `l_4` in that order. Then I use arrow up three times to write `l_2` again. Now how it used to be was, if I use arrow up/arrow down again, I would end up with `l_1`/`l_3`, so it remembers where I last 'went to' (see example in the end). This was very useful whenever I wanted to rewrite a large number of code lines in the same order. Now I switched to Ubuntu, and the arrow up button will always start from the beginning again, i.e. if I used it three times to get to `l_2`, then write line `l_2`, the next arrow up would give me `l_2` again instead of `l_1`, as `l_2` was the last line written. I'm not even sure if this is a Python or Windows/Linux specific setting, but does anyone have an idea how I can get it to do what it used to again?

## Example

(In case it didn't become clear what I mean.)
Say I wrote the following in the Python REPL:

```
>>> x=0
>>> for i in range(10):
...     x += i
...     x *= 2
```

and I want to type the same code fragment once again, I want to be able to rewrite these four lines by using the arrow up button 4 times to acces the first line, `x = 0`, write this line, and after that lines 2-4 should be accessible, in that order, via a single 'arrow down'. However, right now, if I do arrow up 4 times to write `x = 0`, after that the 'position the arrow keys are at' resets, and arrow down won't give me anything, whereas for writing the second line of code, `for i in range(10)`, I would have to use arrow up 4 times again (not 3, because I have already added a new line of code `x = 0`). For large chunks of code, this becomes way more tedious.

Comment: can you provide useful code so we can help more?

Comment: Uhm I'm not sure I can provide more useful code, but I can add an example in the end, maybe then it's more clear what I mean.